# What controls redirection from https://www.host.com to https://host.com?

Tags: redirect, https, dns, no-www, namecheap

Everything but https://www.host.com to https://host.com works:

1. host.com                    --> https://host.com
2. www.host.com            --> https://host.com
3. https://host.com          --> https://host.com
4. https://www.host.com --> ? error

**My DNS Records are like this:**

1. Type: A Record

   - Host: @
   - Value: 111.222.333.444
2. Type: CNAME Record

   - Host: www
   - Value: host.com.
3. Type: URL Redirect Record - unmasked

   - Host: @
   - Value: http://host.com
4. Type: URL Redirect Record - unmasked

   - Host: www
   - Value: http://host.com

Along with some MX records. This DNS is on Namecheap so *I think* `URL Redirect Record` is a `301 Permanent Redirect`.

Also, now after running the URL Redirect Records, `nslookup host.com` returns two different IP addresses.

**What controls that redirection, from https://www to https://non-www?**

On Ubuntu 16, DigitalOcean Droplet, with SSL setup via certbot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error.

The SSL certificate was missing the `www.example.com` version/domain.

Since SSL was installed with Let's Encrypt / Certbot, using `sudo certbot certificates` showed that `Domains:` only had the non-www version.

So redirection was actually working well in all cases except when `https` caught the www version and threw an error due to missing certificate.  Also, redirects 3 and 4 in the original post were unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using apache you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exampledomain.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://exampledomain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

then

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite;
sudo service apache2 restart;
```

Comment: I checked and already had similar, functional rewrite rules in apache `conf` file.